# How to execute stored procedure with out values via ADO.net 2.0 using c# correctly?

Tags: c#, ado.net, interbase

I have large database (InterBase 2007) with a lot of stored procedures which
I'm trying to call from my c# code. The problem only with stored procedures with output values. Usually i catch exception like ("message length error (encountered 0, expected 8)" or "unassigned code") I should notice that command text which I've build in my code works if I compile it from SQLEditor in IBExpert, but not from my application.

Please help me deal with this issue.

Thanks.

If I call a stored procedure without some returns, code that I present below works.

I've tried to add parameter objects for all types of params (inputs and output) but it leads to "unassigned code" exception.

Example #1_

```
        try {
            DbCommand xCommand = pCmdObj;

            xCommand.CommandText = $"execute procedure IFS_INSERT_PURCHASE ('{pUP_unit.Transfer.ExtNumber}',"
                    + $"'{DateTime.Parse(pUP_unit.Transfer.CurrentState.Transact.LocalDateGMT)}',"
                    + $"'{DateTime.Parse(pUP_unit.Transfer.CurrentState.Transact.LocalDate)}',"
                    + $"'{pUP_unit.Transfer.CurrentState.Transact.Terminal.Number}',"
                    + $"'{pUP_unit.Transfer.CurrentState.Transact.Terminal.Name}')";
            xCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();// here is exception if sp has retutns
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            //"message length error (encountered 0, expected 8)"
            return true;
        }
```

For a stored procedure which returns data, I've tried something like this:

Example #2:

```
        xCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            xCommand.CommandText = "IFS_INSERT_IN_FILE";
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                xCommand.Parameters.Add(xCommand.CreateParameter());
                xCommand.Parameters[i].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
            }
            xCommand.Parameters[0].ParameterName = "@ORDER_TYPE";
            xCommand.Parameters[0].DbType = System.Data.DbType.String;
            xCommand.Parameters[0].Value = pUP_unit.Transfer.Type;

            xCommand.Parameters[1].ParameterName = "@TRANSACTION_NUM";
            xCommand.Parameters[1].DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32;
            xCommand.Parameters[1].Value = Int16.Parse(pUP_unit.Transfer.TransferDetails.FileDetails.Transfer_no);     
             .
        ----//----
             .
            xCommand.Parameters[8].ParameterName = "@USD";
            xCommand.Parameters[8].DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int16;
            xCommand.Parameters[8].Value = 0;

            xCommand.Parameters.Add(xCommand.CreateParameter());
            xCommand.Parameters[9].ParameterName = "ID";
            xCommand.Parameters[9].DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32;
            xCommand.Parameters[9].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                       
        xCommand.ExecuteScalar(); // here is exception"Unassigned code"

        //it leads to "Unassigned code" exception.
```

On step "xCommand.ExecuteScalar();" of 1 example i catch "message length error (encountered 0, expected 8)".

On step "xCommand.ExecuteScalar();" of 2 example i catch "Unassigned code" exception.

Comment: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue is for values returned by the SQL statement RETURN (or similar for your DB). The Output parameters require ParameterDirection.Output

Comment: Just to clear this thing. If the second example is following the first example, did you remove the return false in the try block? Otherwise the program will never reach the second example code (as stated by the compiler)